# Can someone help me understand why W orthogonal consist of these to matrices in that example?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the full question: [image]

**I am interested in the sub-question c)**
Here is the solution that I want to understand:[image]

I see that in the solution they first compute the scalar product of the basis of W with each element of the basis of $M2x2$. They than notice that two of them does not give orthogonality.

Afterwards, I don't see how they come up with $W orthogonal$. I've noticed that the first matrix in that basis corresponds to the first element of the basis $M2x2$ which did not give $0$ when scalar multiplied with the basis of $W$. As for the second matrix, I don't know how it was obtained and this is what I want explained.

Comment: You should really learn to use MathJax, which is what’s used for formatting mathematical expressions here, instead of posting pictures of your work and asking people to decipher your scribbling, however neat it may be. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There’s a big problem here: $W^\perp$ is three-dimensional, but this purported basis only has two elements.